# Selecting the values from the database through sqlite in iPhone

Tags: iphone, select, sqlite

I am developing an iphone application using sqlite. In that, I have a method to retrieve the values from the table which is shown partially.

```
NSString *sqlQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat: @”select * from %@”, tableName];
If(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [sqlQuery UTF8STRING] , -1, &statement, NULL)== SQLITE_OK)
{
While(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
{
}
Sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
```

What my doubt is , inside the while loop we can get the values of the column through the index of the table like the following code.

```
NSString *addressField = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
address.text = addressField;
```

For one column we can retrieve like this. In my case, I don’t know the number of columns to be retrieved. In this case, how to iterate over the columns. Please help me out.
Thanks.

Comment: I think you must know the count of columns or you are adding them during the application work ???

Comment: You can store somewhere the count of columns and then write

Comment: i think while loop is used for number of rows and not for columns my friend..

Comment: @vito brothers: yeah it is like a generic class.

Comment: @dks1725. yeah that loop is for rows only. but we need to know the column names to retrive .

Comment: you can do one thing before this you can fire one more query to find no of columns in your table

Comment: you don't need to know column name ... you only need to know count

Comment: NSString *addressField = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];NSString *addressField = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];NSString *addressField = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];NSString *addressField = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)];

Comment: @vito: yes correct. i know the column count and i want to iterate it using the count. how it could be done??

Comment: Don't forgot than you can accept the answer witch helps you !!! Good Luck !!!

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *sqlQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat: @”select * from %@”, tableName];
If(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [sqlQuery UTF8STRING] , -1, &statement, NULL)== SQLITE_OK)
{
While(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
{
int columnCount = YouKnowColumnCount;
NSMutableArray* array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for( int i=0; i<columnCount ; ++i) {
    [array addObject:[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, i)]];
}
Sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
```

Something like this it depend what do you want to do ...